# Converting json map to csv using jq

Tags: bash, jq

input

```
{"key1": ["value1", "value2"], "key2": ["value3"]}
```

Desired output

```
key1, value1
key1, value2
key2, value3
```

Having a hard time figuring out jq command to achieve this... I have tried map, as, to_entries filters in various combinations but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the extra pair of brackets around your JSON object in order to make it a valid JSON. So, starting with this:

```
{
  "key1": [ "value1", "value2" ],
  "key2": [ "value3" ]
}
```

We apply `to_entries`, which gives us this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "value": [ "value1", "value2" ]
  },
  {
    "key": "key2",
    "value": [ "value3" ]
  }
]
```

Then, we `map` each of those entries and we spread (`[]`) the `.value` array, creating a separate object for each of its elements (`map({key, value: .value[]})`). This gives us:

```
[
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "value": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key": "key2",
    "value": "value3"
  }
]
```

After that, for each of those objects, we want an array with its values, since that's what the `@csv` filter expects. That's just mapping to an array object, as in `map([.key, .value])`, which gives us:

```
[
  [ "key1", "value1" ],
  [ "key1", "value2" ],
  [ "key2", "value3" ]
]
```

And, finally, we spread (`[]`) the array of arrays (since `@csv` expects individual arrays) and we pipe `@csv` to it. The full script looks as follows:

```
jq -r 'to_entries | map({key, value: .value[]}) | map([.key, .value])[] | @csv' test.json
```

And its output:

```
"key1","value1"  
"key1","value2"  
"key2","value3"
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago for step by step explanation. Updated the question to remove the extra brackets (was a result of me trying to simplify the input for the post)

Answer (score 1):

You can skip a few steps building up the rows.

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | { key, value: .value[] } | [ .key, .value ] | @csv'
```

In jq 1.5, you can utilize the new `combinations` filter to generate combinations of the keys and values.

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | [ [.key], .value ] | combinations | @csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution using just jq's `[]` operator and `\()` string interpolation.  Use along with the jq `-r` flag to avoid extra quotes in final output.

```
  . as $v
| keys[]
| "\(.), \($v[.][])"
```